# Обособление оборота

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот

> Я не горел желанием едва покинув город возвращаться в него.

Нужно ли обособить оборот "едва покинув город"? Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Деепричастный оборот, как правило, обособляется независимо от места, занимаемого им по отношению к глаголу-сказуемому:
не горел желанием возвращаться — что сделав? — едва покинув город.

**Я не горел желанием, едва покинув город, возвращаться в него.**

[Деепричастный оборот разделил составное сказуемое. В этом предложении оборот лучше поставить в начале:
*Едва покинув город, я не горел желанием возвращаться в него.*]

***Едва покинув город,*** парень подобрал ожидавшего его Заморыша, свернул с мощёной дороги на грунтовую и крупной рысью поскакал на северо-запад.
Д. Ракульт. Игра на выбывание

*И боевая машина пехоты, **едва покинув территорию поселка,** резво набрала скорость.*
С. Самаров. Двенадцать раундов войны

[Обособление деепричастного оборота](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0/)

Answer (score 1):

Деепричастный оборот ***едва покинув город*** по правилам положено выделять запятыми:

*Я не горел желанием, едва покинув город, возвращаться в него.*

Comment: Точнее, _деепричастный_ :)

Comment: Спасибо за уточнение, Alex_ander. Бывает.:)